# how can i put photos without background as tkinter icon?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI using tkinter, I have some Button icons on my screen, that when user clicks, they execute their specific function. for example this one:

```
    def screenshot():
        # root.iconify()
        myScreentshot=pyautogui.screenshot()
        file_path=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
        myScreentshot.save(file_path)
    
    screenshot_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/app6.png')
    screenshot = tk.Button(root,image=screenshot_image,bg='#0000CD',command=screenshot)
    screenshot.place(x=640,y=500)
```

the problem is icons image. when I use the image as a button icon on my page, they always have a square or a rectangle on their background, although I use `bg` to set its color like my main page but I can still see it has a background.

How can I simply display the shape of the image without the background of the shape?

[image]

Comment: You need to use a png with transparent background as icon. This is not really a programming question.

Comment: so have can i have a transparent background for my png?

Comment: You need to create it with a graphics editing program.

Comment: use ttk components instead of tk components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square or rectangle is called the "relief". It is one of the visual cues that this is a button that can be pressed.

If you don't want that, set it to "flat":

```
screenshot = tk.Button(
    root,
    image=screenshot_image,
    relief="flat",
    bg='#0000CD',
    command=screenshot
)
```

I would however advise you *not* to do this. The relief is there so that buttons are recognizable as such. Removing that in some places makes for an inconsistant user interface which can confuse new users.